# Get distinct count pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

i have mongodb document

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c1"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(1), 
"UserName" : "user1", 
"DeviceId" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15T18:20:02.896+0000")


"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c2"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(2), 
"UserName" : "user2", 
"DeviceId" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15T18:20:02.896+0000")


"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c3"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(3), 
"UserName" : "user3", 
"DeviceId" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15T18:20:02.896+0000")


"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c4"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(4), 
"UserName" : "user4", 
"DeviceId" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15:20:02.896+0000")


"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c5"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(5), 
"UserName" : "user5", 
"DeviceId" : "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15T18:20:02.896+0000")


"_id" : ObjectId("55a6a66e072bfb0dcc1d83c6"), 
"IdUser" : NumberInt(6), 
"UserName" : "user6", 
"DeviceId" : "cccccccccccccccccccccccccc", 
"RegTime" :  ISODate("2015-07-15T18:20:02.896+0000")
```

i want result Count Deviceid Distinct  in day in monthy
2015-07-15 =CountDeviceDistinct = 3 {aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccccc}

Answer (score -1):

I think you should group by date and collect device ids in field like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [{ $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$date" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" }, year: { $year: "$date" } }, DeviceIds: { $addToSet: "$DeviceId" }
    }}
   ]
)
```

Comment: Please do not ever use a `$project` stage that could otherwise be directly integrated into `$group`. This also does not answer the question asked by "counting distinct" occurances for each "DeviceId" value that the OP asked for.

Comment: @SergiuZaharie Nope. Still will not address the issue that the OP is asking. It's pretty simple if you actually know how to solve this.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, you were right, needs an unwind and extra group by DedviceId.

Comment: @SergiuZaharie Nope. Much easier way to solve than that.